# how to go to ubuntu 16.04 after installed alongside window 10 dual boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-10

how to go to ubuntu 16.04 after installed alongside window 10 dual boot
it only strait goes to the window 10 
where should I find the option to goes to the ubuntu ? 
window 10 is installed in ssd and ubuntu is installed in another hard drive

Comment: Are both Windows and Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode?  Is the other hard drive an internal drive (or USB)?  What model machine is this.  More information would help us give you an answer.

Comment: yea seemed like both system installed in UEFI

Comment: If both in UEFI mode, can you invoke the EFI menu (some function key at power up to allow selection of boot device or OS) and select "ubuntu"?  If that works, you just have to move the ubuntu entry to the beginning of the boot order.